# Disadvantages of sharding PostgreSQL in 2022

Tags: postgresql, sharding

I'm in the phase of choosing a database for a project, PostgreSQL seems to be the best choice.

I read many questions at stackoverflow and other websites about Sharding database, they were all about MySQL and old ones. Not what i was looking for.

I want to know what are the disadvantages of sharding PostgreSQL in 2022?

**Can we have/do?**

- Consistency
- Performance (Speed)
- Joins (inner join, left join, subquery, etc)
- Transactions

Comment: This depends completely on the sharding solution you are choosing. Partitioning with FDWs? Citus? Something else?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the 4 things i've written in the question are my concerns. I've not chosen anything.

Comment: Btw I'm not sure if you mentioned this in any of your previous questions, but how much data do you have today?...how much data do you project having in 1 year?...10 years? I ask because I wonder why you think you need sharding now before you've finalized a database system. (Don't get me wrong, it's good you're trying to plan upfront.) From my experiences of working with 10s of billions of rows, in a single table for `Messages` type of data, I didn't need sharding. But your case may be different, details considered.

Comment: @J.D. for now 0, i don't know. Its a chat app, millions of users will be messaging in p2p and group chats. There are fast messaging apps like Telegram, They have built their own database system, Users want fast delivery/read/write. Keeping all messages in a table makes queries slower even after tuning, 0.00001ms is important. One day ill need to shard.

Comment: Nanosecond response time? For a chat application?

Comment: @mustaccio i mean losing that ns or whatever, is intolerable , not as a response time.

Comment: Users are unable discern a wait time of less than a few hundred milliseconds (there's some good studies on this). So forfeiting a single nanosecond being *intolerable* sounds unrealistic for anyone to try to accomplish. Even sharding won't be of any more benefit than other solutions in that regard. Fortunately writing and reading from a table should only take a few milliseconds in general, when things are working properly.

Comment: @J.D. Well a single nanosecond was just an example, i didn't even know it was a nanosecond (extra 0s), Don't take it seriously. But intolerable because i don't want to be lazy, i want to try all possible solutions to decrease the response time. I'm overthinking, maybe because i had a bad experience with mysql 5 years ago.

Comment: Gotcha, if it makes you feel better, Facebook still uses MySQL today even being one of the first proponents of NoSQL a while ago. They actually use both systems now for different use cases in different databases, but they stored their `Messages` data in MySQL. [This article gives metrics](http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/11/4/facebook-at-13-million-queries-per-second-recommends-minimiz.html) to the standards they achieved / went by (e.g. 4ms reads). Its a little old of an article but still true. So no need to try to beat Facebook by a unicorn of a number with performance. RDBMS is capable.